# Draw Component in Canvas Without draw already drawed component again

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I try to draw bitmap in touch points when touch move i need to draw the bitmap in newly added position not redraw the whole points again how to achieve that.

i try the following

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
            drawPanel.setPaths(new PointF(event.getX(),event.getY()));
            drawPanel.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);Z
    if(point != null) {
        for (PointF pointF : points)
            canvas.drawBitmap(shape, pointF.x, pointF.y, paint);
    }
}
```

i know its draw again the loop.  I need continue to draw the newly position only how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

onDraw needs to draw the entire view.  So there is no way to draw only the new touches in onDraw.

What you can do is create a memory bitmap, and draw new touches to the bitmap in onTouch.  Then draw the bitmap to the screen in onDraw.  Since the bitmap will never be cleared, you only have to add touches to it.